# Binding DropdownList in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have created domain model and define entities, value objects, Services and so on. Now, my query is that i have an entity called "Company" which has around 20+ attributes and i want to bind a dropdownlist control in one of my page that require only two attributes i.e. company.Name, company.Id. Why should i use such a heavy entity having 20+ attributes to bind the dropdownlist.

Is there any way to handle this considering the performance in mind as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why the community wiki on this one?

Comment: It's happen by mistake, could u plz guide me to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not that much DDD related. It's about performance.

As I do - I do not care if there is 1 or 20 attributes as long as those attributes does not come from separate tables. There isn't high difference if select picks up 1 or 20 fields, but there is noticeable difference if select starts to join other tables and there is highly noticeable difference when there's [select n+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

So - when I retrieve list of `Company` through my ORM in order to create selectlist, it is smart enough to run sql select only over `Company` table and lazy load other things if they are necessary (which aren't in this particular case).

Luckily - I'm not developing systems that demands ultra high performance so I don't care if it takes 1 or 20 fields. If I did - I doubt that I would use ORM anyway.

---

For some other persistence mechanisms - it might not be a problem at all. E.g. - if You are using document database, You can store/retrieve whole aggregate into one document cause it's schema less. Performance penalty goes down drastically.

Comment: What you suppose to do if Company has BLOB for company logo with average size about 1 MB?

Comment: @gandjustas I would lazy load them.

Comment: It's not only fetching the aggregate, processing it & passing it to client also consume more resources & bandwidth. Implementing DDD is itself a challenge but optimization is more challenging than that...

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I would either consider a Reference Data Service returning lightweight representations of the domain model or preferably (for simplicity) implement caching.  Either way remember this is only something you should really worry about **after** you've identified performance of the architecture to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic key/value model and expose a method from your service that returns your company name / company id list. This is similar to other value type data you query your DB for (ex state code / state id).

Answer (score -3):

DDD is not about performance. With DDD you should operate "aggregates" - consistent set of connected entities. Aggregates should be loaded from datatbase into application memory.
Ah-hoc queries (actually almolst all queries) considered in DDD as "Reporting", and should be done by separate mechanisms like denirmalized databases.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-command-query-separation-as-an-architectural-concept.aspx

it's bullshit. Don't use DDD.

Write queries when you need. Use Linq to compose-decompose queries.

Comment: I almost upvoted you, until I read the last two senteces. What you say is bs.

Comment: @epitka it's not. at least - not when looking from his context. :)